# Converting a MOV to WEBP

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency, webp

I have a transparent video that I would like to include on my website with a background behind it. I am trying to convert it to .WEBP via ffmpeg.

I have previously succeeded in converting it to .WEBM, but many browsers don't support it, so I thought trying .WEBP. Although .WEBP is also not supported on all browsers, there is a JS package to fix that: http://webpjs.appspot.com/

I have tried **(A) from .mov to .webp directly** and **(B) first from .mov to .webm to then go to .webp**
The conversion to .webp isn't correct. The new frames are rendered over the old ones. This question had the same problem, but it doesn't start from a .Mov like me so I doesn't help me: [Transparent animated WebP not clearing frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864497/transparent-animated-webp-not-clearing-frames)

**A)**

ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec libwebp -lossless 1 -qscale 0 -preset none -an -vsync 0 -loop 1 output4.webp

**B)**

ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -b:v 0.5M  -filter:v "crop=in_w*4/6:in_h" -c:a libvorbis -auto-alt-ref 0 -vf scale=960:540 output.webm

ffmpeg -i output.webm -vcodec libwebp -lossless 1 -q 60 -preset default -an -vsync 0 -loop 1 output.webp

My goal is to try webp as a way to show transparent animations.
(GIFs are to big, APNG is not supported and also to big).

**If someone has another alternative, let me know! I rather not started coding them in actual html/css/js, because an animator already took the time to make them in after effects...**

Comment: Related: https://gist.github.com/dreampiggy/52c658253de3ba22fd3dec4d3f3182ab

Comment: That's not a programming question. As such, it's off-topic here. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to get an introduction.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with frames overriding each other. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a proper solution of converting .mov with alpha into .webp using FFMPEG.

As a workaround, I convert .mov into .png-sequence (in my case Adobe After Effects) and then pass it to the img2webp converter with simple command like([link](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/img2webp)):

```
 img2webp -o output.webp -q 40 -mixed -d 66.66 *.png
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [pattern sequence](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) to name the output files:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libwebp -lossless 1 webpee-%04d.webp
```

In this example the files will be named `webpee-0001.webp`, `webpee-0002.webp`, `webpee-0003.webp`, etc.

Remove `-qscale 0 -preset none -an -vsync 0 -loop 1` as these are either default, ignored, or unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of "new frames are rendered over the old ones" when using `libwebp`. But not when using `libwebp_anim` instead.

These worked for me to produce animated .webp files from a video with alpha channel, or from a sequence of .tiff files with alpha:

```sh
in="test-prores-w-alpha.mov"; out="test.webp"
ffmpeg -i "$in" -c:v libwebp_anim -lossless 1 -loop 0 -preset default -an -vsync 0 "$out"
```

```sh
in="test-tiff%08d.tif"; out="test-2.webp"
ffmpeg -r 25 -i "$in" -c:v libwebp_anim -lossless 1 -loop 0 -preset default -an -vsync 0 "$out"
```